# How to get api token of bugzilla login

Tags: python, shell, rest, bugzilla, gitzilla

I am trying to make use of curl command which will help me to update the bug status after providing details ..
So I am trying to run this specific curl command to do it, however it gives an login error.

Curl command which I am running :

```
curl --request PUT --header "X-BUGZILLA-API-KEY: MY_INSTANCE_API" "https://BUGZILLA_INSTANCE.com//rest/bug/6819?status=RESOLVED"
```

Error:

```
{"documentation":"https://bugzilla.readthedocs.org/en/5.0/api/","error":true,"code":410,"message":"You must log in before using this part of Bugzilla."}
```

The thing is that, I need to login to bugzilla to perform this task, for that I can't provide the token which can be used as my login and password.. I tried to search it in my bugzilla instance but unable to find it.

The documentation is also not that clear,
Can someone tell me once where and how I can find or create the token for my login and pass of bugzilla ?

Reference :  https://bugzilla.readthedocs.io/en/5.0/api/core/v1/general.html#authentication

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything in the docs you linked that says you can use an X-header to pass the API key.  It looks like it wants `&api_key=KEY` on the URL to me.

Comment: Thank @justdave ! You saved my life :D I was searching for the answers on whole internet and there was nothing mentioned about this.